# How to write items in a list

Tags: expressions, writing

In the formal document like thesis, How to write items in a list? For example:

A lot of studies are done, in structural aspect, algorithmic aspect and applications.

(what I mean here is, for one problem, we can do studies from different aspects, for example, we can study its structure, its algorithms and its application.)

For me it sounds strange that the first two items have aspect but the last one does not. But it should be in applicational aspect or in application aspect?

Comment: First of all, I think "A lot of studies are done, in" is unclear. Do you mean that studies must take many aspects (or factors) into account? Also, it is unclear what is meant by "structural aspect, algorithmic aspect and applications". What exactly do you mean by each item here? Maybe you could say "Studies must take many factors into account, such as structure, algorithms, and application". But can you explain what you mean by "a structural aspect" - what are some examples? - and also "application" - application (verb) of what? Or do you mean types of applications (nouns)? If so, which ones?

Answer (score 1):

I would say something along these lines:

> *When analyzing a problem, we can view it structurally, algorithmically, or by application.*

If I understand your question right, you're wondering if it's okay to break up the parallelism of the list (you did so by dropping the word *aspect*; I did the same thing by switching from an adverb to a prepositional phrase).

In any case, the answer is yes, it's okay if parallelism is not preserved, particularly when there's no better way to word the sentence. In your sentence, you are mentioning the structural and behavioral aspects of a problem, along with how that problem might be used in a more general application. All three elements are part of the same list, but they can't be expressed using the same grammatical structure. That's not a problem; for example:

> Yesterday, we visited the mall, the zoo, and then we ate dinner at a fancy restaurant.
>
> At the zoo, we saw lions, zebras, and other animals from Africa.
>
> At the restaurant, the waitress took our order, brought us our food, and we left her a big tip because she was so cordial.

Each of those sentences does the same thing, in a way. If the broken parallelism sounds awkward, or introduces some confusion or ambiguity, that can usually be fixed by using two sentences instead of one:

> Yesterday, we visited the mall and the zoo. Then we ate dinner at a fancy restaurant.
>
> At the zoo, we saw lions and zebras. We saw other animals from Africa, too.
>
> At the restaurant, the waitress took our order, and then brought us our food. Afterward, we left her a big tip because she was so cordial.
>
> *When analyzing a problem, we can view it structurally or algorithmically. We can also examine it by application.*